# AR.js video element overflows screen size

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

Video element overflows screen size on mobile devices like this:

[image: 1]

But on desktop it doesn't overflow screen.

I tried to replace style attribute of HTML element <video>:

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" playsinline="" id="arjs-video" style="width: 1426px; height: 1069.5px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: -2; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -50.25px;"></video>
```

But it returned to previous state and CSS properties didn't work.